# How to turn on the network indicator automatically when using internet

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Any way to turn on the network indicator automatically when connecting to internet? I know I can use `UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true / false` to turn on or turn off the indicator. But, if I have 10 or more view controllers, I need to implement this 10 times or more. Any way to implement this only once? Thanks.

Comment: Create factory method for network request, then call it there

Comment: Do you mean if I use Alamofire, I need to edit their request functions?

Comment: I normally create a couple of methods in the app delegate that increment/decrement a counter and set the activity indicator to true/false based on non-zero/zero. You can then call the increment before you send a request and decrement in the completion handler.

Comment: @Paulw11 You should make that an answer.

Comment: @Paulw11 it still require to call in each viewcontroller if he don't have a singleton/factory network class

Comment: If you're using Alamofire, which based on your comment you may be, then look at [AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator)

Comment: Ya. Instead of Alamofire, I still have another method to connect internet

Comment: So which are u using? Alamofire or NSURLSession?

Comment: @Tj3n Yes, but that isn't very difficult and it means that each view controller doesn't have to worry about what other requests are active,  but you are right, viewcontrollers shouldn't be performing network operations anyway; some other object should be handling that.

Comment: I am using Alamofire and Parse to fetch data

Comment: @PakHoCheung Then just use the Alamofire network indicator

Comment: @Tj3n OK. Thanks a lot